# Cannot compare strings

Tags: python

I am relatively new to python and I cannot get this simple string comparison to work. No matter what I type into the terminal, even if I type 'a', I get "Invalid Input". If anybody can help me find what I am doing wrong that would be great. I have also tried to assign answer choices in variables (ans1 = 'a', ans1 = 'b') but it seems to behave the same.
Thank you

```
while True:
    pref = (input('Choose a or b '))

    if (pref != 'a') or (pref !='b'):
        print('Invalid input')
        time.sleep(2)
        continue
    else:
        break

print('same')
```

Comment: `pref != 'a' or 'b'` is _not_ the same as `(pref != 'a') or (pref != 'b')`

Comment: Put this a or b inside the round brackets. ('Choose a or b')
while True:
    pref = input('Choose a or b')
    if pref != ('a' or 'b'):
        print('Invalid input')
        time.sleep(2)
        continue
    else:
        break

print('same')

Comment: I have updated the code to include the parenthesis. I still get invalid input when typing 'a' or 'b'.

Comment: Try this: 
`if not ((pref == 'a') or (pref == 'b'))`:

Comment: `if (pref != 'a') and (pref != 'b'):` also works and is shorter and perhaps more readable.